# ios7.1 beta - which version do i need?

Tags: ipad, ios7

I'm trying to access the beta version of `7.1` but there are 2 version for the `3rd Gen iPad` with `3G`.  One is for AT&T, the other is for Verizon... but my `iPad` is UK version and as far as I know is neither of these.

Anyone know which I should download?

I did find this out months ago but it took for ever and I have lost my notes (and memory apparently).

Thanks
Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

First: Wifi only
Second: Cellular with SIM card slot
Third: Cellular without SIM card slot

But this question is really an off topic and could be easily done our good old friend, Google.

Comment: this allows to clearly see the version

Comment: Thanks!  I had no idea that was the difference.  I guess it must be the way I google, but results I kept getting were basically rehashes of the Apple instructions.  I must have spoken to about 20 different people at Apple last time (passed back and forth from Developer support to Product support) and they couldn't tell me this. Huh. Why they have to have a completely different model number for my iPad is a mystery.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page](http://www.apple.com/ipad/LTE/) there is no European version available for 3rd Generation iPad. The only ones available are `iPad with retina display (3rd Generation) model A1430` which is for I believe a United States and Canada model number and `iPad with Retina display (3rd Generation) Model A1403` which is United States model as well. If your model number matches `A1430` or `A1403` (Which I don't it will) you can try one of them or you could risk using the Wifi only version (Which doesn't seem to be in that list which models it will work on) but [here is the download dmg](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/ios/ios_7.1_beta_3_r9zgcv/ios_7.1_beta_3__ipad_wifi_3rd_generation__11d5127c.dmg) (This may expire)

[image]

Comment: That was the problem I had last time.  There model number shows as MD370B/A.  I'll follow the advice above as I definitely have a SIM card.

Comment: @Bertie My recommendation would be unless your model number is included it isn't worth the risk. Someone at my company made this mistake last time for an iPhone 5 and they bricked it and we had to return it and get a new one, all because they didn't want to ask for advice of me - it was quite annoying. But it is your decision no one else's. They do model numbers for a reason and it can void your warranty if you stick the wrong one on.

Comment: Hahaha, I just noticed there is a second model number on the case which says A1430.  So partially my bad for assuming that the model number (in Settings->General->About) was, actually, the model number. But c'mon Apple wtf do I need 2 model numbers for?  Anyway A1430 it is...

Comment: @Bertie Normally the model number can be found on the back of the device. Glad you found it though.